# Массовый поиск и замена, но только в тех папках, имена которых указанны в txt файле

Tags: shell, sed

Делаю массовую поиск и замену в php файлах такой командой:

```
find -type f -name \*.php | xargs sed -i 's|что заменить|чем заменить|'
```

Подскажите как сделать, так что бы он искал не во всех папках, а только в тех, имена которых указаны в текстовом файле `list.txt`.

Содержимое файла list.txt:

```
foldername1
foldername2
foldername3
и тд.
```

Поиск и замену в этих папках нужно делать рекурсивно

Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Позиционные параметры утилиты **find**(1) задают имена каталогов, откуда начинать поиск. По умолчанию GNU версия ведёт поиск из текущего каталога. Чтобы передать имена папок в параметры find, сделайте так:

```
find `cat list.txt` -type f -name \*.php | ....
```

Правда, это сработает, если в именах ваших каталогов нету пробелов.